# Make the pose position equal to the rest position

Tags: armature, bones, pose-mode, inverse-kinematics

I want my rest position to be my pose position (make pose position = rest position), because the when I duplicaed one side of my armature to make the right side, one of the arm got flipped and its only present in the pose position, so I was wondering if I could make it equal to the rest position or if there was an other way to make it symmetrical. Also, if one of you is patient enough to take a look in my blender file, could you tell me how to make my foot look at the pole target as the rest of the leg (the foot as set offset to the leg controller bone) and make it so when my leg controller goes too far down, the foot dont follow it ? Thank you (also I just noticed the right leg is very slightly not symmetrical too in pose mode)

my project: [project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13oPK4rJQuXMJ106jL1chpc0jwh5cdrmY/view?usp=sharing)

[image: rest position (good)]

[image: pose position(not symmetrical)]

[image: Foot not following pole target]

[image: Foot following the ik too far]